# How determine architecture of a Convolution Neuronal Network

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning

How determine architecture of a Convolution Neuronal Network

I'm doing some research on deep learning in computer vision.

I read a lot about how neuronal networks , back propagation, stochastic gradient descent, overfitting, regularization and so on works.
There are 'hard' mathematical rules: that's easy to understand.

But, how do I know what for a architecture I need for my Convolution Neuronal Network?
For Exmaple: I want to classify these plants:
http://www.biohof-waldegg.ch/Bilder/Blacke%201%20(Individuell).JPG

I have studied examples with the mnist database (handwritten digit database)
- why use the most examples these architectures: Conv 5x5 -> Pooling(2,max) -> Conv5x5?
  I have plotted the weights of the first hidden layer, but the image filters looks not very
  familiar for me (nor like a high pass filter for edge detection, nor like a low pass filter)

- is it better to add more feature maps in a layer or to add more hidden layers?
- how can I determine if the Network is too deep / too shallow
- how can I determine if a layer has too much / too less feature maps?
- how can I determine if the kernel size is too big / too small?
- when i chose conv -> conv -> pooling instead of conv -> pooling -> conv?
- what for an impact has the stride parameter? (I know what this parameter does, but not when and how i have to adjust these parameter?
- is there a way to check *which* features a Layer is detecting? (e.g. edges / color / shapes)

Comment: There are too many questions here, you should split it into several questions. Also be aware that many of these questions have an answer of "trial and error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard, proven rules how to construct neural networks (or CNNs). This is an open problem.

> why use the most examples these architectures: Conv 5x5 -> Pooling(2,max) -> Conv5x5

This is not the case. Most architectures use 3x3 pooling, because subsequent pooling layers expand the perceptive field to arbitary sizes. Empirically, some researchers (e.g. [Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567)) found that those work better.

> how can I determine if the Network is too deep / too shallow

- The inference is too slow -> the network is too deep
- The accuracy is too low -> depth could help

> how can I determine if the kernel size is too big / too small?

Just use 3x3 as default. See [Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567) for the reason.

> When do I chose `conv -> conv -> pooling` instead of `conv -> pooling -> conv`?

I would rather write `conv -> conv -> pooling` instead of `conv -> pooling`, hence the question is "how do I determine how many subsequent convolutional layers I should have. Again, this is an open problem. Most people choose 2 or 3 subsequent convolutional layer, but at the end it seems to boil down to "just try it". (Please let me know if there is a more engineering approach!)

> What for an impact has the stride parameter?

Stride reduces the size of the output feature map. Hence it reduces your memory footprint a lot (* 1/stride^2).

> is there a way to check which features a Layer is detecting?

Zeiler & Fergus: [Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901)